# Open telemetry pod fails on AKS with failed to get config

Tags: azure-aks, open-telemetry-collector

I am applying the following yaml manifest to the AKS cluster

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: default-otel-collector
  annotations:
    # We want to create this after the CRD's are created. Argo starts at zero
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "1"
spec:
  mode: deployment
  autoscaler:
    maxReplicas: 18
    minReplicas: 2
    targetCPUUtilization: 80
    targetMemoryUtilization: 80
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 1Gi
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 1Gi
  # Only needed for daemonsets which aren't used here
  #serviceAccount: default-otel-collector
  tolerations:
    - operator: Exists
  #hostNetwork: true
  # Environment variables here can be passed to the config
  env:
    - name: HONEYCOMB_ENDPOINT
      value: "api.honeycomb.io:443"
    - name: REGION
      value: "REPLACE_ME"
    - name: LOG_LEVEL
      value: "INFO"
    # When honeycomb is ready, uncomment this
    # The collector will fail if the secret isn't there
    - name: HONEYCOMB_API_KEY
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: honeycomb-auth
          key: api-key
    - name: KUBE_NODE_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
  #ports:
  config: |
    receivers:
      jaeger:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          thrift_binary:
          thrift_compact:
          thrift_http:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          http:

    processors:
      batch:
      memory_limiter:
        check_interval: 1s
        limit_percentage: 90
        spike_limit_percentage: 10
      #k8sattributes:
      #    filter:
      #        node_from_env_var: KUBE_NODE_NAME
      attributes/eks:
        actions:
          - key: collector_host
            value: "$KUBE_NODE_NAME"
            action: upsert
          - key: region
            value: "$REGION"
            action: upsert
      transform/refreshbreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "mentos:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "mentos:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "mentos:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
      transform/refreshbreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "mentos:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "mentos:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "mentos:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "mentos:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "mentos:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
      transform/aggregationbreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION receive"
      transform/aggregationbreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "qpoc:ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "qpoc:ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "qpoc:ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "qpoc:ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION receive"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "qpoc:ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION receive"
      transform/deletebreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:IDENTITY_ACCOUNT_DELETE receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:IDENTITY_ACCOUNT_DELETE receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:IDENTITY_ACCOUNT_DELETE receive"
      transform/deletebreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "qpoc:IDENTITY_ACCOUNT_DELETE receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "qpoc:IDENTITY_ACCOUNT_DELETE receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "qpoc:IDENTITY_ACCOUNT_DELETE receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "qpoc:IDENTITY_ACCOUNT_DELETE receive"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "qpoc:IDENTITY_ACCOUNT_DELETE receive"
      transform/wpsbreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "wps:REQUEST receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "wps:REQUEST receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "wps:REQUEST receive"
      transform/wpsbreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "wps:REQUEST receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "wps:REQUEST receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "wps:REQUEST receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "wps:REQUEST receive"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "wps:REQUEST receive"
      transform/streamingaggbreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "StreamingAccountResourceAggregation.handleMessageInternal"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "StreamingAccountResourceAggregation.handleMessageInternal"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "StreamingAccountResourceAggregation.handleMessageInternal"
      transform/streamingaggbreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "StreamingAccountResourceAggregation.handleMessageInternal"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "StreamingAccountResourceAggregation.handleMessageInternal"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "StreamingAccountResourceAggregation.handleMessageInternal"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "StreamingAccountResourceAggregation.handleMessageInternal"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "StreamingAccountResourceAggregation.handleMessageInternal"
      transform/promoAttrbreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "mentos:IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PROMOTION_REQUEST receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "mentos:IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PROMOTION_REQUEST receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "mentos:IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PROMOTION_REQUEST receive"
      transform/promoAttrbreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "mentos:IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PROMOTION_REQUEST receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "mentos:IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PROMOTION_REQUEST receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "mentos:IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PROMOTION_REQUEST receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "mentos:IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PROMOTION_REQUEST receive"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "mentos:IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PROMOTION_REQUEST receive"
      transform/identChangebreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "identity:IDENTITY_CHANGED receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "identity:IDENTITY_CHANGED receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "identity:IDENTITY_CHANGED receive"
      transform/identChangebreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "identity:IDENTITY_CHANGED receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "identity:IDENTITY_CHANGED receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "identity:IDENTITY_CHANGED receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "identity:IDENTITY_CHANGED receive"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "identity:IDENTITY_CHANGED receive"
      transform/batchSourcebreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "BATCHED_SOURCE_ACCOUNTS_RESPONSE receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "BATCHED_SOURCE_ACCOUNTS_RESPONSE receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "BATCHED_SOURCE_ACCOUNTS_RESPONSE receive"
      transform/batchSourcebreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "BATCHED_SOURCE_ACCOUNTS_RESPONSE receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "BATCHED_SOURCE_ACCOUNTS_RESPONSE receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "BATCHED_SOURCE_ACCOUNTS_RESPONSE receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "BATCHED_SOURCE_ACCOUNTS_RESPONSE receive"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "BATCHED_SOURCE_ACCOUNTS_RESPONSE receive"
      transform/qpocRefreshbreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive" 
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
      transform/qpocRefreshbreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "qpoc:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "qpoc:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "qpoc:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "qpoc:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "qpoc:REFRESH_IDENTITY receive"
      transform/qpocSyncbreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:SYNCHRONIZE_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:SYNCHRONIZE_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "qpoc:SYNCHRONIZE_IDENTITY receive"
      transform/qpocSyncbreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "qpoc:SYNCHRONIZE_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "qpoc:SYNCHRONIZE_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "qpoc:SYNCHRONIZE_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "qpoc:SYNCHRONIZE_IDENTITY receive"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "qpoc:SYNCHRONIZE_IDENTITY receive"
      transform/mentosAttrPrombreakChild:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "IdentityAttributePromotionMessageHandler.doInlineRefreshWithLock"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "IdentityAttributePromotionMessageHandler.doInlineRefreshWithLock"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", parent_span_id.string], "")) where attributes["sp.parent_name"] == "IdentityAttributePromotionMessageHandler.doInlineRefreshWithLock"
      transform/mentosAttrPrombreakParent:
        error_mode: ignore
        trace_statements:
          - context: span
            statements:
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originTrace"], trace_id.string) where name == "IdentityAttributePromotionMessageHandler.doInlineRefreshWithLock"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.originRoot"], "yes") where name == "IdentityAttributePromotionMessageHandler.doInlineRefreshWithLock"
              - set(attributes["sre.test.id"], Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "IdentityAttributePromotionMessageHandler.doInlineRefreshWithLock"
              - set(trace_id.string, Concat(["1000000000000000", span_id.string], "")) where name == "IdentityAttributePromotionMessageHandler.doInlineRefreshWithLock"
              - set(parent_span_id.string, "0000000000000000") where name == "IdentityAttributePromotionMessageHandler.doInlineRefreshWithLock"
      filter/dropaudit1:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.iris.event_type'
                value: AUDIT_WHITELISTED
      filter/dropmentos2:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.messaging.payload_type'
                value: IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_PROMOTION_REQUEST
      filter/dropqpoc1:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.messaging.payload_type'
                value: STREAMING_ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION
      filter/dropqpoc2:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.messaging.payload_type'
                value: STREAMING_IDENTITY_MANAGER_CORRELATION
      filter/dropqpoc3:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.messaging.payload_type'
                value: IDENTITY_ACCOUNT_DELETE
      filter/dropqpoc4:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.messaging.payload_type'
                value: ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION
      filter/drophecate1:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.messaging.payload_type'
                value: 'STREAMING_ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_AGGREGATION'
      filter/dropcreatecert:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.messaging.payload_type'
                value: CREATE_CERTIFICATION
      filter/dropaudit2:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.messaging.payload_type'
                value: AUDIT_EVENT
      filter/dropaudit3:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'name'
                value: 'CloudProvisioningLibrary.createAuditEvent'
      filter/dropaudit4:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'name'
                value: 'CloudProvisioningLibrary.auditIdentityRequestItems'
      filter/dropaudit5:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.parent_name'
                value: 'CloudProvisioningLibrary.auditIdentityRequestItems'
      filter/dropaudit6:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: strict
            attributes:
              - key: 'sp.parent_name'
                value: 'CloudProvisioningLibrary.generateAuditsFromItems'
      filter/droptoofast:
        spans:
          exclude:
            match_type: regexp
            attributes:
              - key: 'duration_ms'
                value: ^0\.0(1|0)[0-9]*
    exporters:
      otlphttp:
        endpoint: "$HONEYCOMB_ENDPOINT"
        headers:
          "x-honeycomb-team": "$HONEYCOMB_API_KEY"

    extensions:
      health_check:
      pprof:
      zpages:

    service:
      extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [jaeger,otlp]
          processors: 
            - batch
            - memory_limiter
            - attributes/eks
            - transform/refreshbreakChild
            - transform/refreshbreakParent
            - transform/aggregationbreakChild
            - transform/aggregationbreakParent
            - transform/streamingaggbreakChild
            - transform/streamingaggbreakParent
            - transform/identChangebreakChild
            - transform/identChangebreakParent
            - transform/promoAttrbreakChild
            - transform/promoAttrbreakParent
            - transform/wpsbreakChild
            - transform/wpsbreakParent
            - transform/deletebreakChild
            - transform/deletebreakParent
            - transform/batchSourcebreakChild
            - transform/batchSourcebreakParent
            - transform/qpocRefreshbreakChild
            - transform/qpocRefreshbreakParent
            - transform/qpocSyncbreakChild
            - transform/qpocSyncbreakParent
            - transform/mentosAttrPrombreakChild
            - transform/mentosAttrPrombreakParent
            - filter/dropaudit1
            - filter/dropaudit2
            - filter/dropaudit3
            - filter/dropaudit4
            - filter/dropaudit5
            - filter/dropaudit6
            - filter/dropmentos2
            - filter/dropqpoc1
            - filter/dropqpoc2
            - filter/dropqpoc3
            - filter/dropqpoc4
            - filter/dropcreatecert
            - filter/drophecate1
            - filter/droptoofast
          exporters: [otlphttp]
      telemetry:
        logs:
          level: "$LOG_LEVEL"
```

I can see in both default-otel-collector-collector-1 and default-otel-collector-collector-2 pods the following event -
Back-off restarting failed container otc-container in pod default-otel-collector-collector-1/2_monitoring(11c0586a-e937-420e-8551-a0d9fbcb73d6)

When I look into pods log I can see the following message

```
Error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:* error decoding 'processors': unknown type: "transform" for id: "transform/deletebreakChild" (valid values: [resource span probabilistic_sampler filter batch memory_limiter attributes])2023/11/21 21:55:07 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:* error decoding 'processors': unknown type: "transform" for id: "transform/deletebreakChild" (valid values: [resource span probabilistic_sampler filter batch memory_limiter attributes])
```

Comment: Hello Alexey, can you explain me little bit on the transform processors section of your YAML. From where are you getting these type values? The error suggests that "transform" is not a recognized type for processors, and it lists valid values. Could you once refer to the official Open telemetry doc for transform Processors section once- https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/configuration/#processors
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/transformprocessor/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to successfully deploy Open Telemetry Collector on AKS, whatever may be the deployment mode (using helm, etc.), you’ll probably need a configuration file for your collector, you will need a deployment file, a service file and some app to capture the logs.
I am creating the same as below-

> $ vim configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: collector-config
data:
  collector.yaml: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols: 
          grpc:
    processors:
    exporters:
      logging:
    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: []
          exporters: [logging]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: agent-config
data:
  agent.yaml: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols: 
          grpc:
    processors:
    exporters:
      otlp:
        endpoint: "opentelemetrycollector.default.svc.cluster.local:4317"
        insecure: true
    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: []
          exporters: [otlp]
```

> $ vim opentelemetry.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: opentelemetrycollector
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: opentelemetrycollector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: opentelemetrycollector
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: otelcol
        args:
        - --config=/conf/collector.yaml
        image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.18.0
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /conf
          name: collector-config
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: collector.yaml
            path: collector.yaml
          name: collector-config
        name: collector-config
```

> $ vim service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: opentelemetrycollector
spec:
  ports:
  - name: grpc-otlp
    port: 4317
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4317
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: opentelemetrycollector
  type: ClusterIP
```

**Output:**

```
$ kubectl apply -f configmap.yaml 
configmap/collector-config created
configmap/agent-config created

$ kubectl apply -f opentelemetry.yaml 
deployment.apps/opentelemetrycollector created

$ kubectl apply -f service.yaml 
service/opentelemetrycollector created
```

$ vim business-app.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: quay.io/jpkroehling/generate-span-java:0.1.0
      - name: agent
        image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.18.0
        args:
        - --config=/conf/agent.yaml
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /conf
          name: agent-config
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: agent.yaml
            path: agent.yaml
          name: agent-config
        name: agent-config
```

**Output:**

```
$ kubectl apply -f business-app.yaml 
deployment.apps/myapp created
```

We now have a collector instance up and running, exposed the OTLP port that we declared in our configuration and there is a service definition that satisfies the requirement.
Time to test it. Yes, I can see both my collector and 'myapp' application pods are up and able to collect the logs.

[image]

Reference Documents:

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/transforming-telemetry/
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/transformprocessor/README.md
https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/configuration/#processors